# How do you translate "A person who admits ignorance shows it once; the one who tries to hide it shows it often." to Japanese?

Tags: translation, proverbs

I have read that this proverb is of Japanese origin (correct me if I'm wrong), but was unable to find its Japanese form. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: I don't think this is a translation request... That said, I think no well-known Japanese proverb means this. The internet is somehow full of strange "Japanese-origin" proverbs known to no Japanese people... Maybe [this](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%83%BD%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E9%B7%B9%E3%81%AF%E7%88%AA%E3%82%92%E9%9A%A0%E3%81%99) is a bit close?

Comment: [This](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%80%E6%99%82%E3%81%AE%E6%81%A5%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AC%E3%81%AF%E4%B8%80%E7%94%9F%E3%81%AE%E6%81%A5) might also be close. Although it doesn't translate to the sentence you provided, the core message seems similar.

Comment: @Yosh あ、確かにそれっぽい！